# Tags dissapear when parsing XML file in java?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am tasked with parsing an XML file. The XML file is of the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestConfiguration>
<Deployment name="PreUpgrade" description="First Test Target">
    <Server>
        <!-- AnalyticsURL Needs to point to the analytics page -->
        <!-- XmlpURL Needs to point to the BI Publisher page -->
        <!-- ex: <AnalyticsURL>http://servername:9704/analytics</AnalyticsURL> -->
        <!-- ex: <XmlpURL>https://servername/xmlpserver</XmlpURL> -->
        <!-- ex: <VaURL>https://servername/va</VaURL> -->
        <!-- If you are using a test certificate on the server for SSL and want to
             to bypass SSL certificate validation, set the IgnoreSSLCertErrors to true.
             This setting is strictly for Test environments only -->
        <AnalyticsURL></AnalyticsURL>
        <XmlpURL></XmlpURL>
        <VaURL></VaURL>
        <UserName></UserName>
        <Password></Password>
        <IgnoreSSLCertErrors>false</IgnoreSSLCertErrors>
    </Server>
</Deployment>
<Deployment name="PostUpgrade" description="Second Test Target">
    <Server>
        <!-- AnalyticsURL Needs to point to the analytics page -->
        <!-- XmlpURL Needs to point to the BI Publisher page -->
        <!-- ex: <AnalyticsURL>http://servername:9704/analytics</AnalyticsURL> -->
        <!-- ex: <XmlpURL>https://servername/xmlpserver</XmlpURL> -->
        <!-- ex: <VaURL>https://servername/va</VaURL> -->
        <!-- If you are using a test certificate on the server for SSL and want to
             to bypass SSL certificate validation, set the IgnoreSSLCertErrors to true.
             This setting is strictly for Test environments only -->
        <AnalyticsURL></AnalyticsURL>
        <XmlpURL></XmlpURL>
        <VaURL></VaURL>
        <UserName></UserName>
        <Password></Password>
        <IgnoreSSLCertErrors>false</IgnoreSSLCertErrors>
    </Server>
</Deployment>
</TestConfiguration>
```

I am trying to change the value of the "name" attributes within the Deployment tags. I am doing this with the following code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder(); 
Document doc = documentBuilder.parse("config.xml")

Node firstDeployment = doc.getElementsByTagName("Deployment").item(0); 
Node firstDeploymentName = firstDeployment.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name"); 
firstDeploymentName.setTextContext("FIRST_DEPLOYMENT"); 

Node secondDeployment = doc.getElementsByTagName("Deployment").item(1); 
Node secondDeploymentName = secondDeployment.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name"); 
secondDeploymentName.setTextContext("SECOND_DEPLOYMENT"); 

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance(); 
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(); 
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc); 
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("config.xml")); 
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

The config.xml file is within the directory that I am invoking my Java application from. The issue I am facing is that after I run my program, the XMl file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><TestConfiguration>
    <Deployment description="First Test Target" name="FIRST_DEPLOYMENT">
        <Server>
            <!-- AnalyticsURL Needs to point to the analytics page -->
            <!-- XmlpURL Needs to point to the BI Publisher page -->
            <!-- ex: <AnalyticsURL>http://servername:9704/analytics</AnalyticsURL> -->
            <!-- ex: <XmlpURL>https://servername/xmlpserver</XmlpURL> -->
            <!-- ex: <VaURL>https://servername/va</VaURL> -->
            <!-- If you are using a test certificate on the server for SSL and want to
                 to bypass SSL certificate validation, set the IgnoreSSLCertErrors to true.
                 This setting is strictly for Test environments only -->
            <AnalyticsURL/>
            <XmlpURL/>
            <VaURL/>
            <UserName/>
            <Password/>
            <IgnoreSSLCertErrors>false</IgnoreSSLCertErrors>
        </Server>
    </Deployment>
    <Deployment description="Second Test Target" name="SECOND_DEPLOYMENT">
        <Server>
            <!-- AnalyticsURL Needs to point to the analytics page -->
            <!-- XmlpURL Needs to point to the BI Publisher page -->
            <!-- ex: <AnalyticsURL>http://servername:9704/analytics</AnalyticsURL> -->
            <!-- ex: <XmlpURL>https://servername/xmlpserver</XmlpURL> -->
            <!-- ex: <VaURL>https://servername/va</VaURL> -->
            <!-- If you are using a test certificate on the server for SSL and want to
                 to bypass SSL certificate validation, set the IgnoreSSLCertErrors to true.
                 This setting is strictly for Test environments only -->
            <AnalyticsURL/>
            <XmlpURL/>
            <VaURL/>
            <UserName/>
            <Password>
            <IgnoreSSLCertErrors>false</IgnoreSSLCertErrors>
        </Server>
    </Deployment>
    </TestConfiguration>
```

It seems as if the opening tags for AnalyticsURL, XmlpURL, VaURL, UserName, and Password are removed from the file when they should not be? Am I doing something wrong with my code? I have tried to figure out where i've gone wrong but cant seem to come up with a solution.

Comment: are you sure it is `</AnalyticsURL>` and not `<AnalyticsURL/>`

Comment: My apologies, it is <AnalyticsURL/>. What does this mean?

Comment: `<AnalyticsURL/>` is a short way of writing `<AnalyticsURL></AnalyticsURL>`. It's just putting the start and end tag in one. It means exactly the same in XML. So the meaning of your input and output XML is exactly the same.

Comment: If I were to edit the <AnalyticsURL> tag afterwords, would it resort back to its original formatting? (opening and closing tag)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
```

([Java XML dom: prevent collapsing empty element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209527/java-xml-dom-prevent-collapsing-empty-element))